# Create Mailbox in Exchange 2003 using C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2003

Please could someone tell me the recommended way to perform common tasks in Exchange 2003 from a C# app? I'm rewriting an old VB app that used CDOEXM.DLL but I'm having loads of problems adding that as a reference to my VisualStudio2010 IDE. The VB app is mainly for adding/updating user details in AD but it does speak to Exchange too.

I need to create a mailbox and set various settings on it.

I've no experience with this at all but I belive there are a few options: CDOEXM.DLL, some Web Services (not sure if they work with 2003 though) and maybe some PowerShell scripts.

If someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it. Deadlines looming...!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Exchange.Net](http://en.codeplex.com/) project.

Comment: Hey, thanks I'll have a look. Is this project widely used and recommended for production use? As it's not official MS code, I'll be asked whether it's suitable/safe/better than any other alternatives by my managers so any additional info would be great. I can't see any docs either but I'll dig around the code and take a look at what it can do for me. Thanks

Comment: I've had a quick look at this now and it looks good but I think we may be after a more official solution so I was wondering if people think PowerShell is the better way to go?

Comment: It depends on you. The codeplex project is not official and as it uses deprecated WebDAV, it is suitable for Exchange Server 2003/2000. If you need support for future versions of Exchange sever, go for "Exchange Web Services" and "Powershell" to get more flexibility.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I would like to give it a try but I know that my managers would prefer a more 'official' solution so I'll give PowerShell a try. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ah, just re-read your answer Alireza. Will PowerShell work with exchange 2003? Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course. I didn't mean that Powershell doesn't work with ES 2000/2003. I referred to its flexibility to work with different versions. Read http://www.messagingtalk.org/how-to-managing-exchange-2000-2003-using-powershell-part-i

Comment: Excellent, thanks again for clarifying that and for the link, very useful.

Comment: Anyone know if I should be using the 'New-Mailbox' cmdlet or the WMI flavour of powershell commands?